# I don't understand what if (indexpath.row < array.count) means?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm really struggling to understand what this is saying.
If a row is selected and it is less than the number of elements in the array then do this...

It doesn't sink in. Please help.

Comment: Show more code around this so there is some context. As-is all we can say is what you already know - the select row is less than the count of elements in the array.

Comment: please make the question more meaningful.

Comment: Quite likely some guard code to prevent an out of bounds error being triggered on the array

Comment: generally, this would be to prevent an array out of bounds exception but it depends on the scenario. example: say, `array.count` returns `4` but the index starts from **0 to 3** so when `indexPath.row` reaches `3`, it should stop else it will go to `4` and not get any array index `4`... ***boom***

Comment: unclear/broad/offtopic - sorry

Comment: Well he needs a basic C course. You cant not really jump on ObjC without C knowledge. The first time you hit an underlying framework you are lost.

Comment: You guys are right.  I will work on making my questions more specific and with code next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the given `array` is used to fill a table view's content and this line occurs in a selection-related method.

The variable `indexpath` refers to a specific item in your table (probably the *selected* row depending on the method in which this line occurs). It countains two indices: `row` and `section`, the first being the 0-based index of the item in a given section.

I also suppose that if the condition evaluates the `true`, you are going to use `indexpath.row` to get an element in the `array`. If that is the case, not performing that check would expose your code to the possibility of going beyond your array bounds.

**Less than** `<` is used here because the array and `indexpath.row` are both 0-based indices, so the maximal index value in the array is its count *minus* 1.

Comment: Thank you. I apologize for making this question so vague, you're explanation really helped me. I will work on making my questions more specific and with code.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't hesitate to ask more questions as you progress, we're here to help :)

Comment: so your next question should be why did this mechanism get put in place?  most tableview/collection views use a single array to populate the rows (in a section).  But it looks like yours may be using array plus another source to populate rows.  Thats fine, just a condition you need to pay attention to if you are updating someone else's app.

Answer (score 0):

if(indexpath.row < array.count)  Lets break this down

indexpath.row
 the class of indexpath has a variable name row, it will contain a value, which will be determined by either row's preset value or with a value set in indexpath's code.

array.count
.count is one of those handle tool that is provide for us, it simply just gives you the number of elements in the array

now lets put it all togather
if(the value if row located in indexpath  < the number of elements in the array)

Hope this helps

Robin

Answer (score 0):

A count will allways return the amount of objects. Like this:

```
NSArray *bowlWithFruits = @[@"Apple 1",@"Apple 2",@"Apple 3"];
```

Counting the objects in the array would tell you there are 3.

So far for the count. Objective C is a superset of C, means we work with C in the firstplace. In C you refer to to offset of the element in your collection and this is the same thing in our ObjC collections. To reffer to the @"Apple 1" you would say [bowlWithFruits objectAtOndex:0] or in modern syntax bowlWithFruits[0]

And now comes the index into play, but I think you can guess what our index actually is. He is just an straight offset.

So when we compare the indexpath for the last element in our example against the count of objects then we compare actually 2 against 3. There is no objectAtIndex:3 just as there cant be an indexpath with a rowvalue of 3.

That is why you compare indexpath.row < array.count.

Comment: Helge, thanks for your explanation. I appreciate you going over the basics. It helps.

Comment: You are welcome. But I guess I got the question wrong. However, Im glad you got the answer you needed.